# Capybara issue inside a within block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

```
  require "spec_helper"
  require "rails_helper"

  include Capybara::RSpecMatchers
  include Capybara::DSL

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

  feature "Course", :type => :feature do
    scenario "Get index and search for course types", js: true do

      visit "/courses"       
      within("//body") do
        find(:xpath, "//input[@id='course_type_id_1']").click
        find(:xpath, "//div[@class='course-right-sec']")

        expect(page).to have_content('65,171 courses')
        expect(page).to have_content('Fundamentals of Design')
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem i am facing with the above code is that when i find a specific div inside a within block, whether the id of the div is correct or not it passes the test.

Comment: Did you solve this? Because I'm experiencing problems with find in within block as well...

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, this is a lot of expectations for one test.  While some testing purists would say one expectation per test, feature tests that need to load js are time consuming, but you might be doing too much here.  One logical way would be to have one feature test for each of your courses; that way you have a couple expectations for each.

This isn't the exact solution to your problem, but it will help debugging in the future.

All of your expectations are based on the have_content matcher.  Basically, if it's in the DOM on load, all of these expectations are going to pass, regardless of your find and click events. Ie. `find(id).click`

I might be able to help more if you give more context to whats going on here and what you are trying to test for and against.  Attaching your js would help also.

Comment: The problem is that the test should fail if it does not find a specific div with correct id, regardless of the correct id the test passes. It should not pass with wrong div id.